# AWS : ELB : Route 53 : Nginx : naked domain redirect

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, nginx, dns, load-balancing

**Setup**
I have two rails app instances running in Opsworks Layer.
I am using Route 53 and an ELB to route traffic to my Layer.

**Objective**
To redirect naked domain traffic to my www domain. 
chicken.com -> www.chicken.com

**What I tried**
I Alter my nginx conf (on one instance) to solve this problem. I added the following:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name chicken.com;
 return 301 $scheme://www.chicken.com$request_uri;
}
... rest of config here
```

**Result**
Instance is no longer hittable by its IP.

ELB marked the instance I had altered as "Out of Service" since it could no longer be reached by IP (the health check fails).

**Question**
How can I route naked domains to www domains yet keep my ELB health checks happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ELB health check expects a 200 response. Are you checking against chicken.com instead of www.chicken.com? A redirect page is not sufficient for the health check.

To have both the redirect and provide a 200 response for the ELB check (coming from an internal IP), use the following config:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name chicken.com;
 return 301 $scheme://www.chicken.com$request_uri;
}
server {
 listen 80 default_server;
 server_name www.chicken.com;
 ...
```

Note the `default_server` option. If not set, the first `server` defined is the default one. See the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

Comment: yes, this is exactly issue. The 301 causes ELB to fail its health check but domain name is not part of the configurable health check on the elb.

Comment: yes and no, and if its the point you are after then I suppose I can mark it correct. The question was 'how can I route the naked domains yet keep my ELB checks happy', not 'whats wrong with my nginx conf in its current state'.

Comment: The redirect is fine, but check for the www.chicken.com URL instead of the plain one on the ELB. Doesn't that cover all your requirements?

Comment: No, because AWS ELB checks do not include full urls they are checks against the instance itself.